# Making symlink with pypy intalled via brew

Tags: macos, bash, homebrew, symlink, pypy

I recently formatted my Mac OS X Mountain Lion and I installed `pypy` using `brew -v install pypy` as always. However, this time, when I hit `pypy` in the terminal, bash reported `command not found`.

I went check and brew did install `pypy` in the normal directory `/usr/local/Cellar`, but there is no link to `pypy` in `/usr/local/bin` as it used to have.

I made an `alias` with my mouse and moved it to `/usr/local/bin`. Then I typed:

```
chmod 755 pypy
```

And I tried to run `pypy` again typing:

```
pypy
```

so...

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pypy: cannot execute binary file
```

Does anybody have any idea of what is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the alias you created with the mouse and create one with :

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/pypy /usr/local/bin/pypy
```

Comment: Aliases created with the mouse are 'understood' only by Finder, not by Bash (in the Terminal). By contrast, symbolic links (created with ln -s) are understood by Bash. They are of different kind. See more information [here](http://macs.about.com/od/faq1/f/What-Are-Aliases-Symbolic-Links-And-Hard-Links-In-Mac-Os-X.htm)